# Как правильно написать слово "нечтение" (антоним чтения)?

Tags: правописание

Встречается два варианта написания: "Нечтение" и "Не-чтение".

Answer (score 4):

Оснований для чрездефисного написания я здесь не вижу. *(Не)чтение* должно писаться или раздельно, если подразумевается, что молодёжь сейчас увлекает *не чтение*, а что-то другое, или слитно, если под *нечтением* имеется в виду какое-то отдельное от чтения понятие.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: нечтение

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Слова "нечтение, неприсутствие" и подобные им отсутствуют в словаре, тем не менее они встречаются в текстах в утвердительных конструкциях и обозначают вполне конкретные понятия, например:

"Бродскому принадлежит еще одно замечательное высказывание: «Нечтение книг я приравниваю к преступлению».

"Подробно о том, как бороться с собственным неприсутствием в реальности, описано в книге Чарлза Тарта «Практика внимательности».

Сравнить: не выполнить - невыполнение (но это сов. вид глагола).

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ Граммы.ру. 
В сочетании с существительными частица "не" может превращаться в словообразовательную приставку. Это происходит в случаях, когда существительное с "не" приобретает значение, противоположное (антонимичное) исходному ***(неправда, неуспех, объяснение в нелюбви и т.п.)***. Особенно часто это происходит с существительными, которые употребляются в терминологическом значении (невыполнение плана, незнание правил и т.п.). Это процесс в полной мере затронул и сочетание "не" со словом "чтение": "Существует преступление более тяжкое — пренебрежение книгами, их нечтение" (И.А. Бродский); ***"Чтение и нечтение в детстве - свидетельство доверия и недоверия к взрослому миру" (В.Н. Волкова);*** "Нельзя вообразить большего культурного нигилизма, более циничного поругания классики, чем ее нечтение!" (Вл. Новиков). В таких контекстах слитное написание совершенно правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого слова. Разве что окказионализм.

Comment: Это слово уже есть. Библиотекари, педагоги, психологи употребляют как термин. Есть проблема в обществе, и она обозначена таким вот простым словом, понятным всем. Поэтому прошу совета у филологов - как правильно его писать.

Comment: В каком словаре есть?

Хоть одну фразу приведите в контексте.

Comment: "Бродскому принадлежит еще одно замечательное высказывание: «Нечтение книг я приравниваю к преступлению».

Comment: Ну, окказионализм... Посмотрите, сколько таких, например, у Маяковского. Можно ли на этом основании говорить, что это слова есть в языке? Нельзя.

У Стругацких: "Повесть о дружбе и недружбе". Слова "недружба" в литературном языке нет. Кстати, подобные окказионализмы с НЕ почти всегда употребляются с основным словом. Тогда они хоть понятны. Вот как у Стругацких.

Если очень хочется написать, надо писать слитно.